# How to POST an array to axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios

I have the following code

```
const onSubmit = data => {

    let params = {
        experience_type: data.education[0].type,
        body: data.education[0].text,
        start_time: data.education[0].from,
        end_time: data.education[0].to,
        
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/experience', params)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);

        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });



  
};
```

I want to POST as the entire data.education array using Axios. Currently I can only post the first index. How would I post all indexes of the data.education array using axios. My current thoughts are to use a spread operator and pass each individually.

Comment: Hey..Can you share across your database  model code

Comment: Please console.log(data) and share the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify(data.education)` to pass the entire data array at once. But you need to handle the collection appropriately on backend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a postgresql database running on the backend which I wanted to insert into row by row. I was hoping there was a way for axios to batch requests or I could use the spread operator to send them individually.

Comment: You can use `FormData` for that purpose. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056214/9971139

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to send the entire object to the express route and then map over the object inserting each row to the database at a time. So one Axios post request and handle the rest in the route as someone else pointed out.

```
 req.body.education.forEach(async values => {



        const newPost = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO Experience (experience_type, start_time, end_time, user_id, author,body,date_created) 
        VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6, NOW()) RETURNING * `,
            [values.experience_type, values.start_time, values.end_time, USER ID HERE, USERNAME HERE, values.body]);

        res.json(newPost[0]);
```

This is how the object is mapped and then inserted into individual rows

Answer (score 0):

This will help you dear fellow.

```
    var axios = require('axios');
    var qs = require('qs');
    var data = qs.stringify({
     'experience_type': data.education[0].type,
     'body': data.education[0].text,
     'start_time': data.education[0].from,
     'end_time': data.education[0].to,
    });
    var config = {
       method: 'post',
       url: 'http://localhost:5000/experience',
       headers: { 
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       },
       data : data
    };

    axios(config)
     .then(function (response) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However doesn't this only apply to the first index in the array? Wouldn't it be easier just to send the whole object and then iterate over it.

Comment: Yeah you can send the complete object and iterate over it on back end. i just adjust it according to your question. cheers!