# can we pass array to post request in react using axios?

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

let assume,
companyDetail is an object, and I have to pass list of company details to API.
so can I d sent array of object in post request like this:-
axios.post("",);

note API is made in ASP.NET Core Web API.

what type of data can we send ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send an array of objects as long as the endpoint expect to receive this type of data.

With axios:

```
const companyDetails = [
  { ... },
  { ... },
  { ... },
];

axios.post("https://myapi.com/companydetails", companyDetails)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: but in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072255/axios-post-array-data , it is show that we have to convert to string by stringify. then what was that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass data as array of object `companyDetail` but its depends on how API request body is created in backend. If API wants request body in some other custom variable lets as `reqBody` the you have to assign your `companyDetail` to `reqBody`

```
axios.post("endpoint", {reqBody: companyDetail})
```

If API wants request body in `companyDetail` itself then:

```
axios.post("endpoint", {companyDetail})
```

Answer (score 0):

> CompanyDetail is an object, and I have to pass list of company details
> to API. so can I d sent array of object in post request like this:-
> axios.post("",);Note API is made in ASP.NET Core Web API. What type of
> data can we send ?

Well, to begin with your first concern, yes we definitely can post list of object as `axios.post("",)` fashion. Considering your scenario we can write that snippet as following:

Let's assume, we have model as below:

Model:

```
public class CompanyDetails
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Asp.net core Web API:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AxiosWebApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CompanyDetails")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CompanyDetails(List<CompanyDetails> companyDetails)
        {
          // Do whatever you like here
            return Ok(companyDetails);
        }
    }
```

> What type of data can we send ?

Well, its up to you, if your controller accept list of object as Model just like this `List<CompanyDetails> companyDetails` then you can do as following.

Axios Request:

```
@section Scripts
    {
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        const CompanyId = "CompnayId:";
        const Name = "Name:";
        const Email = "Email:";
       

        const companyDetails = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            const companyObject = {
                CompanyId: CompanyId + i,
                Name: Name + i,
                Email: Email + i
            }
            companyDetails.push(companyObject);
        }
        console.log(companyDetails);
        axios.post("http://localhost:5094/api/AxiosWebApi/CompanyDetails", companyDetails);
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** If your controller accept `[FromForm]` then append as `FormData()` just like `formData.append("CompanyId", 1);` then push to your array object.

In addition, please check your browser console if the object posted accordingly as following:

[image]

Output:

[image]